# Different JRE name in eclipse causing source control headache

Tags: eclipse

I have a java project that I'm trying to develop across two machines (using eclipse), but they have a .classpath difference between them. On the first machine:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/JVM Contents (MacOS X Default)">
```

the second machine:

```
<classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.launching.macosx.MacOSXType/Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default)">
```

so the difference is:

```
"JVM Contents (MacOS X Default)"
            vs
"Java SE 6 (MacOS X Default)"
```

If I go into Preferences -> Java -> Installed JREs, I can modify the "JRE name" attribute on either one of the machines. But I'm fearful of doing this as it may wreak havoc on all my other projects that might depend on that global name?

Any recommendations on how I could work around this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not reference JREs directly, but only reference an [execution environment](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Execution_Environments) in the project. The execution environment is then mapped/resolved differently on each machine.

You can see how to select an execution environment for existing machines in the second screenshot of [this Eclipse tutorial](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-with-java7.htm&cp=1_1_3).

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense. Works now. Thank you.